# How to loop a mocked list?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing a unit test for a simple method. Since only a single class should be tested in a unit test, everything else must be mocked. The method accepts a single list; Mocking the input list results in some really weird behavior. The list seems to be empty and non-empty at the same time, even though I set elements with Mockito.

```
class Sum {
  static long sum(final List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
      return -1L;
    }

    long sum = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
      sum += list.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

class UnitTest {
  @Test void sum_single() {
    final List<Integer> listMock = Mockito.mock();
    Mockito.when(listMock.get(0)).thenReturn(42);

    assertFalse(listMock.isEmpty());   // list is non-empty
    assertEquals(42, listMock.get(0)); // the element is in the list!
    assertEquals(42, Sum.sum(listMock));
  }
}
```

The test is failing with the following error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <42> but was: <0>
```

What gives? Somehow, the element in the list is not summed, even though I have put it at index 0 in the list (I even verify the element in the test before testing my class). Furthermore, the list is obviously non-empty as verified in test itself (and if it were empty, the method would return -1).

Why is this test not working? It does everything according to the book: only a single class is tested, all other classes are mocked, the mock is set up with a value. What do I have to change so that the test verifies that the elements in the list are correctly summed?

Comment: Why do you want to mock the list in the first place? Why not use a real one, like an `ArrayList`?

Comment: @ndc85430 this is a question/problem often encountered by newcomers. Somehow we ended up with the notion of "only a single class" and "everyhing must be mocked". It is completely confusing and non-transparent why the list is not empty, but still doesn't sum its elements. Why can't Mockito read our minds?

Comment: _"Since only a single class should be tested in a unit test, everything else must be mocked"_ - not *everything*; for one thing, you generally shouldn't mock what you don't own. Your method accepts a list, unless you're planning a very implementation-coupled test (which TDD should be helping you avoid) using real collections isn't inappropriate. As to why your specific test double is a problem: what's its size?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why did you remove the tags? They are clearly relevant to the question (it is about mocking and _unit_ testing)

Comment: I don't understand how this question is lacking details or clarity? It includes a [mre] (copy-pastable), it states the problem, it asks a single, specific question. I'll gladly add the missing details if you let me know what.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the size of the list? You'd expect it to be 1, because there is one element in the list (`get(0)` returns the element). It is not 1, but why is that? How to explain to someone on their first day of unit testing?

Comment: What is the intent here? Was this supposed to be self-answered, a canonical of some kind? Or do you actually not understand what's happening in the code you've posted? I wouldn't expect the size to be 1, and if uncertain I'd log or debug it. Who's the beginner (_is_ this your first day of unit testing)? What _"misguided "suggestions""_ (and they might be misguided but they're definitely suggestions).

Comment: I think mockito gives you a default implementation for isEmpty returning true all the way.

Comment: @Karsten it's the other way round. The default implementation by Mockito returns the default value for a data type (plus special handling of collections)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Mockito.mock` creates a mock object with no stubbed behavior, which means that all methods will return a default value for their return type (empty collections, 0 for numbers, false for booleans, null for objects).

Stubbing the `get` call does not magically add items to the list and does not affect the return value of `isEmpty()` nor that of `size()`. The mocked "list" is not a real list. It is a mock object without any behavior. An empty shell. It only does what it is explicitly told in the test.

Applying the rules from the first paragraph lets us deduce:

- `mockList.isEmpty()` returns `false` (the default value for a boolean)
- `mockList.size()` returns `0` (the default value for a numeric type)

If Mockito is applied carelessly, you'll end up with zombie objects, which pretend that they are working, while they do not behave like their real counterparts. In case of the list, it seems to be non-empty but has a size of 0 at the same time; that doesn't make sense for a list!

Not everything must be mocked. It is okay to test the interaction between objects (of the same unit). A unit is not a single class! (but it could be). Even Mockito itself [advises against mocking everything](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-everything-its-an-anti-pattern):

> If everything is mocked, are we really testing the production code? Don't hesitate to not mock!

On the same page, they explain that [*value objects* shouldn't be mocked](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-value-objects) either. A list is clearly a value object (it is a data holder without any interesting behavior).

Last but not least, [don't mock types that you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own).

The test becomes a lot shorter, simpler, and more correct by using a real list instance – and it actually works and is testing your logic:

```
class UnitTest {
  @Test void sum_single() {
    final List<Integer> list = List.of(42);
    assertEquals(42, Sum.sum(list));
  }
}
```

---

**TLDR**: Only mock if necessary. It is often easier to start without mocks and only introduce mock objects if it actually makes your tests simpler and more maintainable. Mocks are useful to hide external, complex behavior or to abstract IO, but they shouldn't be used for everything. A "unit" can be more than a single class or a single method.

To quote the Mockito wiki one final time:

> Don't hesitate to **not** mock!