# How to write Junit test for Cosmos container query items?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, azure-cosmosdb, azure-java-sdk

I have a requirement where I need to write Junit tests for the following piece of code. The issue I am unable to figure out how to create an actual dummy instance of `Iterable<FeedResponse<T>>` because if I pass mocked instance of `Iterable<FeedResponse<T>>`,then the for loop in the next step throws null pointer exception as it tries to iterate over the mocked instance and finds nothing in it. Given below are the block of codes from the actual class and test method. Any lead would be highly appreciated.

**Actual class - for loop is the issue**

```
Iterable<FeedResponse<Employee>> feedResponseIterator = cosmosContainer
                        .queryItems(query, queryOptions, Employee.class)
                        .iterableByPage(continuationToken, pageSize);
for (FeedResponse<Employee> page : feedResponseIterator) {
                    }
```

**Test Method - This approach throws null pointer from the for loop as discussed above**

```
@Mock
CosmosClientManager cosmosClientManager;

@Mock
CosmosContainer cosmosContainer;

@Mock
CosmosPagedIterable<Employee> page;
    
@Mock
Iterable<FeedResponse<Employee>> feedResponseIterator;

when(cosmosClientManager.getCosmosContainer(anyString())).thenReturn(cosmosContainer);
when(cosmosContainer.queryItems(anyString(), any(), eq(Employee.class))).thenReturn(page);
when(page.iterableByPage(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(feedResponseIterator);
```

Comment: Can't you return a real `CosmosPagedIterable` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Your iterable doesn't stub any of its methods, meaning that calling `iterator()` on it (which is what the enhanced for loop does) will get you a `null`. Either stub all required calls of the mock (`iterator()` and then return a proper iterator or stub all important methods on the iterator …), or change your code to return an actual `CosmosPagedIterable` instance.

Note that your field is called `feedResponseIterator`, but it is not an iterator but an `Iterable` (an interface on clases which can *return* an iterator)

Here's an example how you could use a real instance:

```
@Mock
CosmosClientManager cosmosClientManager;

@Mock
CosmosContainer cosmosContainer;

@Mock
CosmosPagedIterable<Employee> page;

when(cosmosClientManager.getCosmosContainer(anyString())).thenReturn(cosmosContainer);
when(cosmosContainer.queryItems(anyString(), any(), eq(Employee.class))).thenReturn(page);

// define responses:
final List<FeedResponse<Employee>> = List.of(new FeedResponse<>(...), ...);
// the iterable returns an iterator for the predefined list:
final Iterable<FeedResponse<Employee>> iterable = responses::iterator; 
when(page.iterableByPage(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(iterable);
```

If possible, try to push the real behavior further up in the call chain. Have your container return a real `CosmosPagedIterable` instance for the page.

This related questions explains why it is problematic to mock/stub collections/containers: [Why can non-empty mocked list not be looped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122530/why-can-non-empty-mocked-list-not-be-looped)

Comment: can you help me understand how to return a real CosmosPagedIterable instance for the page? as far as I understand in a unit test, i cannot hit the actual database to return a real CosmosPagedIterable instance.

Comment: @ShivayanMukherjee I assume that a `PagedIterable` can be constructed from in-memory data, without hitting the database. If that's not possible, go with the approach of using a real list, and having the page stub return the real list as iterable (as shown in the answer)