Mocking an object without a getter
I want to mock a function that has following code -
// Getting all ad insights objects from API
Connection<AdsInsights> insightsConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnection(
        adAccountId + "/insights",
        AdsInsights.class,
        Parameter.with("level", LEVEL_OF_INSIGHTS),
        Parameter.with("time_range", "{\"since\":\"" + startDate
                + "\",\"until\":\"" + endDate + "\"}"),
        Parameter.with("fields", fields),
        Parameter.with("time_increment", TIME_INCREMENT));

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

// Iterating over result pages
for (List<AdsInsights> insights : insightsConnection) {
    // Iterating over result of each page
    for (AdsInsights insight : insights) {

I am not able to figure out how to mock insightsConnection object.
I tried mocking it like -
when(insightsConnectionMock.getData()).thenReturn(insightsList);

But this doesn't seem to work, I am still getting null pointer exception while the iteration starts.
P.S The objects are from restFb library

A question very similar in nature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122530/how-to-loop-a-mocked-list (the answer will surprise you, it might not be what you expect)

Java for-each loop is just a syntax sugar over iterator.
Thus:
for (List<AdsInsights> insights : insightsConnection) {
}

is expanded by the compiler to:
for (Iterator<List<AdsInsights>> it = insightsConnection.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    List<AdsInsights> insights = it.next();
}

See https://restfb.com/documentation/:

The Connection object implements the Iterable interface.

